# Executing subsequent command/script, after the current one was ^C

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm failing to find answer to my problem. I need to be able to execute a shell command/bash script after the current one was exited with ^C.

In other words:
I've got a script which is running and just after I ^C from it I want another script or command to launch immediately after. How to achieve this?

I've tried `./first.sh; echo something` with no luck.

I could try to run simultaneous scripts where one would be waiting/listening for the other to finish and then do the cleaning-up commands and also exit. But then I'd need a way of launching them in one command.

What would be the most appropriate approach to this problem?

Thanks 
**EDIT:**
I think I've got it...
From the first script I can launch the other one with & at the end so it goes to the background. Seems to work with ^C exit from the first one (second continuous to work).
Any suggestions on better solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`./script1.sh && ./script2` i.e. execute 2nd if 1st was successful.

`./script1.sh || ./script2` i.e. execute 2nd if 1st was NOT successful.

or in script1 you could trap the exit signal and spawn the second process. Something like this:

s1:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "./s2.sh" SIGINT

echo "hello"
sleep 100
```

s2:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "goodby"
```

session:

```
$ ./s1.sh 
hello
^Cgoodby
```

Comment: Thanks. This is obviously better than creating listener in the background! This is what I've been looking for.

Comment: This solution is not perfect, because you can't check, what command was interrupted in the script. It's quiet possible that you will interrupt the script before the point where the second script must be started. The `&&` and `||` statements obviously will not help also, because non-zero exit code doesn't mean that the program was interrupted.

Comment: It is good enough in my case. I don't care at what point the script was interrupted, and it doesn't impact the behavior of the clean-up script. I did the trap as the very first thing in my first script. If the script is interrupt before that, there's no need for cleanup. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You need to things:

1. You need to trap sigint (ctrl-c) so the script will be not finished when you press ctrl-c
2. After the command was finished, you need to check the reason why it was finished. If command was interrupted with `SIGINT` (signal 2), the exitcode of th command will be 130 (128 + 2).

You make it so:

```
trap "echo ctrl c was pressed" SIGINT
sleep 100
[ "$?" = 130 ] && echo "you've interrupted the previous command with ctrl-c"
```

Example:

```
$ bash 1.sh
^Cctrl c was pressed
you've interrupted the previous command with ctrl-c
```

Comment: Thanks. This is obviously better than creating listener in the background! This is what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Bash Guide for Beginners Chapter 12. Catching signals](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)

> > Here is a very simple example, catching Ctrl+C from the user, upon
> >     which a message is printed. When you try to kill this program without
> >     specifying the KILL signal, nothing will happen:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # traptest.sh
>
> trap "echo Booh!" SIGINT SIGTERM
> echo "pid is $$"
>
> while :           # This is the same as "while true".
> do
>         sleep 60  # This script is not really doing anything.
> done
> ```